# Linking Mysqllib in static library (MAC OS X.8.4, Xcode 4.6.3)

Tags: mysql, c, xcode, macos, api

i´m often using the mysql c api and therefore linking them into my c projects, developed unter xcode.

Yesterday i tried to build up a static library to encapsulate some db functions.

But if i try to build the lib there occur some strange errors:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lm
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lm is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lz
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lz is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

to include the mysqllib under xcode it is necessary to add the following line to the build set-ip "other linker flags":

```
-lmysqlclient -lm -lz
```

As far is i understand xcode is not able to use this linker flags within a static library.

With a normal command line programm it works fine and i use it since years.

Does anyone has a hint for me how to deal with this issue?

Thanks in advance

solick

Answer (score 1):

I getting similar error on XCode 5 while replacing old external libraries with newer iOS7-ready version.

```
ie:
...can't locate file for: -l
...is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

I discovered Xcode5 incorrectly escaping double-quote while inserting library search path to *project.pbxproj*.

```
ie: 

incorrect behaviour ---> "\\\"/path/library/\\\"",   (note: 3 slashes)
correct behaviour  ----> "\"/path/library/\"",       (note: 1 slash)
```

***solution***

Opening up **project.pbxproj** and doing a search and replace quickly fixed my problem.

```
ie: search(\\\) replace with (\)
```

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem: included the mysql lib at the main program this worked for me.